# Suggestions regarding the suggested edit queue being full (again)

Tags: feature-request, review-queues, suggested-edits

I know this is a topic that has come up many times, but I'm just going to go ahead and bring it up again.

The main problem about the edit queue being full: *there are literally thousands of questions which are wrong or misguided and I see them everywhere, yet no one can edit them because the edit queue is full.*

This really does seem a bit ridiculous, seeing as the limit for the edit queue is *500* edits. Because of this, I'm requesting that a feature be added in so you can actually *take back* your edit, or that you can see your edits after you've submitted them.

Because of this, I think a lot of people would be able to re-edit their edit, make it higher quality, or just plain delete it if it's a troll edit or trash.

Comment: *yet no one can edit them because the edit queue is full*: Only users with less than 2k can't edit them. Users with the full edit privilege don't need to be reviewed and are not affected by the edit queue limits. *or that you can see your edits after you've submitted them*: Aren't they listed in your profile > all activities > suggestions?

Comment: I know that, but there's still a limited number of 2k+ users.

Comment: @Forestral well, 2k users aren't that rare, and many of them still parcitipate in editing posts, as I do

Comment: Re *"questions which are wrong or misguided"*: What do you mean by that? Can you elaborate? Do you have some examples? What kind of edits were you planning to do?

Comment: Questions that were homework dumps or just plain 'gimme teh codez'

Comment: *"…there are literally thousands of questions which are wrong or misguided and I see them everywhere, yet no one can edit them…"* Based on this statement, it seems you misunderstand the purpose of editing. Edits aren't for posts that are wrong or misguided. These don't need to be edited. Answers that are wrong should be downvoted. Questions that are misguided, unclear, off-topic, "not even wrong", or otherwise unsuitable for SO should be flagged for closure and/or removal. Homework and "gimme teh codez" Qs are not off-topic; dunno where you got that impression. Or why you want to edit them.

Comment: Most are not troll edits or trash, just suggestions by users trying to do the ***minimum*** amount of work to get the reputation points (typically inconsequential formatting changes). Most potential long-term reviewers turn away in [disgust](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5wAuDhoRmzg&list=PLSoD2CcPrumFJREVL6RmMnZP5U7sGYYi2&index=2&t=9m16s). It is a vicious cycle. The incentives (and if it can't be helped, the punishments) ought to be changed.

Comment: This probably would have gotten a substantially different reception if you had stuck to presenting your feature request, rather than have the title and first portion of your question rehash a topic (suggested edit queue is full) that has been discussed *ad nauseam*. You appear to know that it's been discussed quite a bit, so it's unclear to me why you rehashed that here. If you wanted to justify the feature request by providing background regarding the suggested edit queue being full, then it would have been better to have that at the end of your question and *not* in the title.

Comment: Presumably, based on your emphasis on the suggested edit queue depth being 500, you feel the queue depth should be larger. As has been discussed *many* times, changing the depth of that queue would do **nothing** to actually fix the issues here. The fundamental issue is that *substantially* more edit suggestions are submitted, or desired to be submitted, than there are reviews being performed. Without increasing the ratio of reviews which reviewers desire to perform to suggested edits which are desired to be submitted to > 1, the queue would just increase to whatever limit existed.

Comment: To my understanding  the proposal is to allow reusing "edit in a queue spot" - while it may seem like a reasonable idea it encourages one to add fake placeholder edits in the queue if spot ever opens up and then possibly make different edit with reasonable quality. As result edit queue will always be full take by placeholder edits - making it even less likely anyone would be willing to actually review edits... If my understanding of the proposal is correct consider [edit] to clarify why you don't except this outcome.

Comment: @Forestral - “Questions that were homework dumps”, **stop** trying to improve homework dumps, homework dumps should be deleted and downvoted. They also shouldn’t be answered either

Answer (score 10):

> Because of this, I think a lot of people would be able to re-edit their edit, make it higher quality, or just plain delete it if it's a troll edit or trash.

Few things:

- users can already re-edit their edit
- troll edits are exceptionally unlikely to be retracted. The reason to leave one such edit is ***not*** to later remove it. The proposal makes little sense in this regard
- users leaving trash edits do so either because they do not see them as trash or *despite* that. It is not an issue of them being unable to retract edits - it is an issue that they are left in the first place.

In general, any proposal that does not address the *growth rate* of the edit queue is a temporary one *at best*, since we would be back to the same problem at the end - too many suggested edits/not enough reviews performed. This still applies to the current suggestion. Expecting users who leave suggested edits to take care of their edits themselves does *not* address the growth rate of the queue. Moreover, it does not address *any* problem. Were *all* users conscientious of the suggested edits they left, we would not have problem with the queue, as we would not be getting low quality and inadequate edits at the rate we do right now.

Implementing the ability to retract suggested edits would only help if *all* users suddenly grew the sense of restraint, diligence, and principle that *is already required* when making edit suggestions. Since it is categorically proven that not *all* users possess these, then the proposal has already failed with making any significant impact on the suggested edits queue.

Just to be clear - being able to retract suggested edits would be a "nice to have" feature. There are situations where you might realise the edit was not needed and the lack of ability to remove it can be annoying. Yet, it is a "nice to have" that will not solve problems with the queue of suggested edits.

Comment: As I understand it (from memory, so could be wrong), once a suggested edit is made, it's possible to effectively null it out by updating the edit to submit the same Markdown text as the original version which the suggested edit was submitted against. Doing so effectively removes the edit, but doesn't give either the system or the user back an edit slot until the null-edit completes the review cycle.